# chef clients never check-in to chef server

Tags: chef-infra

We have setup a chef server and now when I try to register a client via the command listed below. The client shows up in the chef server portal but does not seems to check-in or does not show any client related information.

```
knife bootstrap  10.0.34.24 -x ec2-user --sudo -i ~/.ssh/mmc_Dev.pem \
  -N mmcshibboleth -r 'role[infra], role[sudorules]'
```

Answer (score 2):

Chef does not install itself as a service or cron job by default. Use the [chef-client](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/chef-client) cookbook to do so.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out here. 

I'm bootstrapping from chef workstation individual clients. So are you saying that I should be using chef-client cookbook from the workstation, so that all the clients in the environment check into the server?

Comment: The run list of the nodes should include the `chef-client` cookbook.

Comment: I have added chef-client from available recipes into the run list along with Infra and sudorules and still no luck.

Comment: Not sure how you went through the README in only 4 minutes

Comment: Did you apply that run list? Did the output mention chef-client resources?

Comment: This is the error message I'm getting when I run bootstrap command

10.0.14.243 [2017-07-03T01:23:42-04:00] INFO: The plugin path /etc/chef/ohai/plugins does not exist. Skipping...
10.0.14.243 [2017-07-03T01:23:44-04:00] ERROR: Error connecting to https://mmcchefsrv.mmc.local/organizations/mmc/nodes/mmcshibboleth, retry 1/5
10.0.14.243 Chef encountered an error attempting to load the node data for "mmcshibboleth"


Client shows up in the server portal but does not check in. Run list has been applied.

Comment: IIRC only successful runs are reported.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the issue resolved by adding chef server IP address and hostname into /etc/hosts file of the client.

After which tried bootstrapping from Chef workstation and everything worked as expected.

Thanks,